# Sqlite order by strftime not working

Tags: android, datetime, strftime

The time format in my table is like this : **02:59:00 (hh:mm:ss)**.

Have been trying to make the query like this:

```
SQL = "select * from Events Where date = '"+tomorrowDate+"' 
       AND city = '"+mCity+"' 
             order by strftime('%H:%M:%S',start_time) ASC;";
```

However the time order still seems random. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), `strftime` is used to convert datetime to the specified format. You should be able to accomplish the ordering with just:

```
order by time(start_time) asc;
```

or

```
order by datetime(start_time) asc; # if date is included
```

without needing to convert the datetime format.